# Pandas: Plotting x against y automatically sorts x

Tags: plot, pandas

I'm trying to plot one column of a dataframe against another in pandas and got unexpected results. I tracked it down to the x values being sorted before plotting.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure();
data = np.array([[3.2, 3.5, 2.4, 3.5, 3.4, 4.3, 5.4, 3.9, 5.7, 7.4],
                [-0.5, 0.2, 0.1, -0.7, 0.0, -1.0, -1.3, -0.3, -0.3, -0.6]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data.T,columns=['A', 'B'])
df.plot(x='A', y='B')

#try again in matplotlib
plt.plot(np.asarray(df['A']),np.asarray(df['B']),'r-')
plt.plot(data[0,:],data[1,:],'go')
data[0,:].sort()
plt.plot(data[0,:],data[1,:],'co')
```

{image deleted can't post}

The blue plot (from df.plot) has column A sorted before plotting.
The red plot is the original data plotted from matplotlib.

Obviously I can get the plot I want by using matplotlib, but the dataframe plot is unexpected.

Comment: Using pandas 0.10.0, `df.plot(x='A', y='B')` coincides with `plt.plot(np.asarray(df['A']), ...)`. Is that not what you are getting?

Comment: I've got pandas 0.10.1 and the df.plot(x='A', y='B') coincides with the data[0,:].sort(); plt.plot(data[0,:],data[1,:],'co')

Comment: I'm getting the same (good) behaviour with pandas 0.12.0.dev-c9d48b5. So one solution might be to upgrade.